# React native map's Heatmap doesn't work when there is a lot of close points on Anroid

Tags: android, react-native, heatmap, react-native-maps

I am using "react-native-maps": "^0.26.1" and "react-native": "0.61.5". I have an API that returns points and i noticed that the Heatmap from react-native-maps bugs in some circumstances.
It can handle and show a lot of points when they are spread all over the map but when there is a lot of points around one area, on Android, it doesn't show anything but on IOS it works fine (as shown on the pictures below).

On IOS
[image: On IOS]

On Android
[image: On Android]

Both are with 85 points. With 80, i don't have the bug on Android so i am guessing the problem is with the algorithm on android when there is a lot of nearest points, and i don't know how to correct it. Any idea or workaround ? any other case ?

EDIT:

this is the code where the problem appears. It is a simple MapView with Heatmap.

```
<MapView
                    ref={this.initMapRef}
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    style={{height: this.props.mapHeight, width: this.props.mapWidth}}
                    showsUserLocation={true}
                    onUserLocationChange={this.onLocationChange}
                    customMapStyle={mapStyle}

                    {...this.getIsPostingAttr(isChoosingPosition || showSuggestions)}
                    >
                        {events.length !== 0 && 
                        <Heatmap
                            opacity={0.5}
                            radius={30}
                            points={events}
                        />}

                </MapView>
```

I think the problem is about the number of points and the area they are. When i have 500 points all around the world, everything works fine but started at (around) 85 points close to each others, the problem appears on Android.

Comment: Please add the code you've problem with.

Comment: It's done, but i don't think it is about the code